# How to limit Clients Bandwidth from IP Address ? ( Delphi )

Tags: delphi, network-programming, bandwidth

We have a LAN Network and a ADSL Router , I want to build an Application to control traffics of Clients , in fact I want to share Internet in Network with limiting bandwidth of clients .

be careful that there is no any application in clients that connected to the server , just one application in Server that it should control the traffics .

I can limit bandwidth of an Client Application when it connect to the Server with Changing ans Setting it`s IOHandler using Indy Components , but there is no any Client Application in Client Computers , and I want to do that by IP Address ( or Host Name ) ! , is it possible ?!
in fact , we have some IP Address in a Network and we should limit traffic using of these IP Addresses ...

there is an example from Mr Zarko Gajic :

http://delphi.about.com/od/fullcodeprojects/l/aa112903a.htm

but it`s only for monitoring , I want to Control the Traffic ...

How can I do it ?!

thanks before ...

Comment: Why would you want to do that from a Delphi app? That's usually done with a good rooter, or with a Linux router.

Comment: I was curious if there was an API to do this, and I guess there must be something as I found http://www.netlimiter.com/  which provides a ActiveX to do it

Comment: I guess it will install a driver into the network stack. Windows allows for "filter" driver to be installed, which can control what is sent/received to/from the previous and next driver in the stack. But such solution can't be written in Delphi, it would require the DDK and a compatible C/C++ compiler.

Comment: @Robert Love :
thanks , Netlimiter is a tool for limiting software traffic but I want to limit clients bandwidth , if I use it`s solution , I should install my Application on all Clients ...

Answer (score 3):

Basically you wold need to write a proxy, route all traffic through the proxy, track and calculate each client bandwidth, and start to delay clients that request too much. Unless you have a good reason to write your own, there are ready-made solutions, i.e. Squid (https://serverfault.com/questions/79824/limiting-bandwidth-dynamically-in-squid).

Comment: 1+ for squid, even under windows

Comment: thanks , It appears that It will be a troublous job !
I think it`s better to be done with Modem Router !

Comment: Prefer to have a better answer on the "How to".  Don't need another software solution.  Plus, I'm running 2 cell phone services that I'm currently bonding.  I need to know how to create my own version of software that has already done this so I can customize it myself. Please point to some source code or more information about how to go about this situation.